# stored procedure -Print

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure [dbo].[basic_und6] (@name varchar(500), @email varchar(500), @result int out)
as 
begin

Select @result=COUNT(*) from tbl_Students 
where Firstname= @name and Email=@email
print @result
end
```

Given below is the query which I am running to execute the stored procedure

```
**declare @result1 int
execute basic_und6 Amit,'amit@abc.com',@result1 
print @result1**
```

I am getting result as 1.

But according to my understanding, it should have displayed two 1's

First 1 is from the stored procedure print and second 1 from the query which had print statement.

Comment: This is product specific functionality. Which dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your execute statement to this :

```
declare @result1 int
execute basic_und6 Amit,'amit@abc.com', @result1 OUTPUT
print @result1
```

This is because, you haven't specified a variable where the output value must be returned to. The calling statement must do this by explicitly using the OUTPUT keyword. More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx)

> If you specify the OUTPUT keyword for a parameter in the procedure definition, the stored procedure can return the current value of the parameter to the calling program when the stored procedure exits. To save the value of the parameter in a variable that can be used in the calling program, the calling program must use the OUTPUT keyword when executing the stored procedure.

Comment: Ya. Thanks. But can you please explain what's wrong with my query. Why I am not getting two 1's.

Answer (score 0):

No it will show only one 1
when we select a value into a variable the row count will not be shown

Comment: This is my understanding . Stored procedure has print. So it should print the result. Then while executing  I am sending print again. It can use the same value and print it again.